# How to show an Image with pillow and update it?

Tags: python, image

I want to show an image recreated from an img-vector, everything fine.
now I edit the Vector and want to show the new image, and that multiple times per second.
My actual code open tons of windows, with the new picture in it.

```
loop
{
    rearr0 = generateNewImageVector()
    reimg0 = Image.fromarray(rearr0, 'RGB')
    reimg0.show()
}
```

What can I do to create just one Window and always show just the new image?

Comment: What software are you using to build your app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way of doing this is to take advantage of **OpenCV**'s `imshow()` function which will display a `numpy` image in a window and redraw it each time you update the data.

Note that **OpenCV** is quite a beast of an installation, but maybe you use it already. So, the code is miles simpler than my `pygame`-based answer, but the installation of **OpenCV** could take many hours/days...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import cv2

def sin2d(x,y):
    """2-d sine function to plot"""
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

def getFrame():
    """Generate next frame of simulation as numpy array"""

    # Create data on first call only
    if getFrame.z is None:
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,w), np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,h))
        getFrame.z = sin2d(xx, yy)
        getFrame.z = cv2.normalize(getFrame.z,None,alpha=0,beta=1,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

    # Just roll data for subsequent calls
    getFrame.z = np.roll(getFrame.z,(1,2),(0,1))
    return getFrame.z

# Frame size
w, h = 640, 480

getFrame.z = None

while True:
       
    # Get a numpy array to display from the simulation
    npimage=getFrame()

    cv2.imshow('image',npimage)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

That looks like this:

[image]

---

It is dead smooth and has no *"banding"* effects in real life, but there is a 2MB limit on StackOverflow, so I had to decrease the quality and frame rate to keep the size down.

Comment: I tryied to use this solution, var w is undefined. I'm a little bit changes it, so my frame was Image.open('image.png')

Comment: Your code doesn't define w and h, but works quite nicely if I add them in.

Comment: Also, installing opencv took no significant time, just a quick `pip3 install --user opencv-python`, or in my case (since I'm on an old OS), `pip3 install --user opencv-python==3.3.0.10`.

Comment: +1 on opencv taking barely any time to install - I was originally scared off by your warning but opencv-python is only 40 MB

Comment: Please update the code to include w and h.  It's a bit strange and not obvious what that's about since they are local variables.  I added my w and h for my desired window size and bingo it works.  Simply add:
```
# window size
w, h = (800, 640)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that pretty simply and pretty fast with `pygame`.

You write a function called `getFrame()` that returns a `numpy` array containing an image that is calculated by your simulation.

By way of example, I create a 2-d sine wave on the first pass then roll that 1 pixel down and 2 pixels across on subsequent calls to simulate movement.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import pygame

h,w=480,640
border=50
N=0
getFrame.z = None


def sin2d(x,y):
    """2-d sine function to plot"""

    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

def getFrame():
    """Generate next frame of simulation as numpy array"""

    # Create data on first call only
    if getFrame.z is None:
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,h), np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,w))
        getFrame.z = sin2d(xx, yy)
        getFrame.z = 255*getFrame.z/getFrame.z.max()

    # Just roll data for subsequent calls
    getFrame.z = np.roll(getFrame.z,(1,2),(0,1))
    return getFrame.z



pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w+(2*border), h+(2*border)))
pygame.display.set_caption("Serious Work - not games")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Get a font for rendering the frame number
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True

        # Clear screen to white before drawing 
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
       
        # Get a numpy array to display from the simulation
        npimage=getFrame()

        # Convert to a surface and splat onto screen offset by border width and height
        surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(npimage)
        screen.blit(surface, (border, border))

        # Display and update frame counter
        text = basicfont.render('Frame: ' + str(N), True, (255, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (border,h+border))
        N = N + 1

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

That looks like this. In real life it is very fast and very smooth, but there is a 2MB size limit for videos on StackOverflow, so I have generated a GIF with a low-ish frame rate and small-ish size just to keep it under 2MB.

[image]

Obviously you can add in detection of Up and Down arrows to speed up or slow down the animation, and you could detect left/right arrow and Spacebar to go backwards/forwards or pause the animation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Pillow documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) the method `Image.show()` is mainly intended for debugging purposes. On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the standard BMP display utility to show it.

You should take a look at the [matplotlib image library](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html).

You can try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imgplot = plt.imshow(rearr0) # "plot" the image.
```

For each iteration, you can call `imgplot.clf()`, it will clear the plot keeping the axis. I have not tried it, but it should work

Comment: Thank you for your help, but no window has shown up.
I read the "documentary" but it didn't work.

Comment: DId you have any error? I think you can use the animation tool. Take a look in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html).

Comment: Okay, but how do I add new images now?

Comment: The thing is that the images are generated during the loop.

Comment: You need to loop the "imshow" function. You might need to do imgplot.show() as well. If you use ipython, different behaviors can be expected, check the documentation.