# Pillow image.show() instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
    def screen_shot():
       pass
    While 1:
       img= screen_shot()
       #getting image in temp
       img.show()
       sleep(1)
```

Hi ,
this code show all screenshots on window. I want to use `pillow image.show()` to organize screenshots like screen recorder. How I will create stable window to show current screenshot image and when new screenshot image comes it delete old one? I made it with update label in `Tkinter` but it is so slow and have delay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show an Image with pillow and update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719095/how-to-show-an-image-with-pillow-and-update-it)

Comment: That’s shows cv2 or pygame solution and it is have a lots of solutions too. But I want to do with pillow  as I described

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Linux localhost 4.14.117-perf-g1e01151 / aarch64 Android in x11-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to dislike my solutions with [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517079/2836621) and with [pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516624/2836621), I thought I'd write you a third one - with `feh` this time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pexpect
import random
import time
from PIL import Image

# I had to ping-pong between two images to get it smooth and error-free
filenames = [ '/tmp/PIL-0.jpg', '/tmp/PIL-1.jpg']
width, height = 640, 480
im = Image.new('RGB', (width,height), (255,0,0))
im.save(filenames[0])
im.save(filenames[1])

index = 1
viewer = pexpect.spawn(f'feh --title "Image Viewer" -- {filenames[0]} {filenames[1]}')
for i in range(100):
    # Choose a random colour
    colour = tuple(random.sample(range(0, 256), 3))
    print(f'Frame: {i}, colour: {colour}')
    # Fill image with random colour
    im.paste(colour, [0,0,width,height])
    im.save(filenames[index])
    # Tell feh to display next (other) image
    viewer.send('n')
    index = 1 - index

# Tell feh to exit
viewer.send('q')
```

It does around 20fps frame rate with 640x480 images on my Mac.

Comment: Thank you so much i arranged code for myself and it is better solution for me.

Comment: Cool - glad it works for you. Good luck with your project.